# Inverted triangle for active menu item in a mega menu

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to produce something like the following (note the inverted arrow below "Product":
[image]

I want to show an inverted arrow below the active menu item. The mega menu is inside Bootstrap `.container`.

However with my skills this is what I've been able to accomplish so far. There are two overflowing lines from both sides. I have created these using `:before` and `:after` of the arrow element inside the active `<li>`. Challenge is to make them visible only within the range of `.container` below

[image]

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdKaVO)

Comment: @YenneInfo, nope, didn't see it... but see it  now :) Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see the demo link, but already set up this **pure CSS** code for you:

```
<ul>
    <li>Menu item</li>
    <li>Menu item</li>
    <li>Menu item</li>
</ul>

<div class="content">&nbsp;</div>
```

```
ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

ul li {
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 40px;
    background: lightblue;
    position: relative;
}
ul li:hover:before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: 5px;
    top: 40px;
    width: 10000px;
    height: 20px;
    background: white;    
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
         -o-transform: skew(20deg);
}
ul li:hover:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    top: 40px;
    width: 10000px;
    height: 20px;
    background: white;    
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
         -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
}

ul:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background: white;    
}
ul:hover:after {
    display: none;
}
```

It creates a 20px space under the menu items. This space is filled by a `ul:after` element. When hovering the `ul`, the `:after` class gets removed. When hovering the menu items, a `li:before` and `li:after` are shown, which provide a white background and is skewed, making it look like an arrow.

The only downside with this script is that the default white space (presented by `ul:after`) is also removed when hovering the `ul` and not the `li`. Maybe someone can come up with a fix for that.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h5ebxcbz/)

Answer (score 1):

The way you did it is way too complicated. The spaces are due to the height of your pseudo-elements. In this example I deleted your arrows and replace them with CSS triangles, you just need a pseudo element on your open class like this  (I let you tweak dimension and position):

```
.open::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 126px;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 8px 5px 0 5px;
  border-color: #808080 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Example : http://codepen.io/mbrillaud/pen/ZGOqoa?editors=110

Comment: I want the triangular area to be transparent. Using a background color is not the solution. In the demo I have used a transparent image.

Answer (score 1):

***Done the following modifications:*** **[RESULT PEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVXBBM)**

Added `z-index`, adjusted `margin-top` and removed `width` from `:after` and `:befor`e . *The reason you were getting extra white background was because you have given the width as 100vw full viewport which was not needed*

```
 .header .menu > li.open.horizontal > span.arrow {
  background-image:
  url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/imgrvx/white.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 14px;
  height: 7px;
  left: calc(50% - 14px);
  margin-top: 19px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:2;
}
.header .menu > li.open.horizontal > span.arrow:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 7px;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  left: -100vw;
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;

}
.header .menu > li.open.horizontal > span.arrow:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 7px;
  left: 14px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
```

Comment: I want the triangular area to be transparent. Using a background color is not the solution. In the demo I have used a transparent image.